# Django Migration Error: ERRORS: 'choices' must be an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-migrations

I have created models for a blog application. This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICE=(
        ('draft','DRAFT'),
        ('published','Published'),
    )

    title=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length = 250,unique_for_date='publish')
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='blog_posts')
    body=models.TextField()
    publish=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                choices = 'STATUS_CHOICES',
                                    default='draft')
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I tried to migrate models I'm getting the error:

```
ERRORS:
myblog.post.status: (fields.E004) 'choices' must be an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple).
```

Here is my admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import post

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(post)
```

Please can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

`choices` need to refer to the list you've declared above, not a string :

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                            choices = STATUS_CHOICE,
                                default='draft')
```

Comment: subtle bug: `STATUS_CHOICES` is in the OPs code not only wrong as string, but also declared as `STATUS_CHOICE`

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the quotes from STATUS CHOICES in

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                        choices = 'STATUS_CHOICES',
                            default='draft')
```

TO:

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                        choices = STATUS_CHOICE,
                            default='draft')
```

Comment: but now i got an error while i used the command python manage,py makemigrations                                                                                                error:You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'author' to post without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populat
e existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option

Comment: Not an error... just read it carefuly. It is what will be done with your DB table...
 Either specify a default for that field or get on with it...